# Jenkins AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployment error

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to deploy my zipped version of application to Elastic Beanstalk via Jenkins.
My S3 bucket name and Elastic Beanstalk configurations are correct.

```
com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.exceptions.DeployException: com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.getRegionByEndpoint(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/amazonaws/regions/Region;
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.engines.Engine.process(Engine.java:185)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.engines.Engine.perform(Engine.java:119)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:101)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:789)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:730)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:675)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1753)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.getRegionByEndpoint(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/amazonaws/regions/Region;
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.amazon.EngineImpl$DeployFileCallable.<init>(EngineImpl.java:259)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.amazon.EngineImpl.newDeployActor(EngineImpl.java:99)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.amazon.EngineImpl.newDeployActor(EngineImpl.java:64)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.engines.Engine.process(Engine.java:178)
    ... 11 more
```

---

Comment: By the way, in AWS "EBS" stands for Elastic Block Store, not Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like problem with AWS plugin version in the Jenkins. I updated to the latest version available and it worked fine.
There was no other error messages other than this available. But to my luck , i tried updating the cloudbees plugin and it worked.